# Pausing a loop for specific time at a specific time in R

Tags: r, loops, time

I have to run a long loop that updates some data and stores it in my company's server. The problem is that the company runs a back-up routine at midnight, and, for that, they shutdown the server for around 15 minutes.

So, given that I have to write down a file for every iteration, when the server goes down it breaks the loop.

I managed to circumvent the problem by writing the loop as follows

```
for(i in bills.list){
  url = paste0("ulalah",i,"/")
  # Download the data
  bill.result <- try(getURL(url)) # if there is an error try again
  while(class(bill.result)=="try-error"){
    Sys.sleep(1)
    bill.result <- try(getURL(url))
  }

# if iteration is between 23:59:00 and 23:59:40 wait 17 min to restart the loop
  if(as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S")) > 235900 &
     as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S")) < 235940){

    Sys.sleep(1020)

  }
  # Write the page to local hard drive
  write(bill.result, paste0("bill", i, ".txt"))

  # Print progress of download
  cat(i, "\n")
}
```

Problem is, by evaluating the time at all iterations, I lose some precious time. Any more efficient thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simply try to store date. If it fails, it might be you are inside backup window

```
store <- function(data, retry = 10) {
  while(retry > 0) {
    result <- try(write(data, "/some_broken_place"))
    if(class(result) == "try-error") {
      # it might be we are in the backup window 
      cat("I will sleep if it turns out that it's backup time")
      if(as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S")) > 235900 &
         as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%S")) < 235940){
        Sys.sleep(1020)
      }
      retry <- retry - 1
    }
  }
  if(retry == 0) {
    cat("Very, very bad situation - no chance to store data")
  }
}
```

Comment: Liked the retry approach. It allows me to try to go back to the loop before the 15 min threshold, which is probably just an upper bound for the time it takes the routine to finish.

Comment: Great! It's nice to know you've liked it.